# Excluding Portion Of RegEx From Results

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a very large text file that has multiple instances of "CLM*[NUMBER I WANT]*".  I have been able to use regex to *mostly* obtain this thanks to another user on this site, but the results I'm getting are displaying the CLM* portion, when I really just want the number.  You can see the relevant code below.

```
Dim strClaimData As String = ""
Dim strClaimNumber As String = ClaimLoadedGetCLM(strClaimData)
Public Function ClaimLoadedGetCLM(ByVal ediString As String) As String
    Dim regex As New Regex("CLM\*(\d*?\*??\d*)")
    Dim ClaimMatches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(strClaimData)
    For Each strClaimData As Match In ClaimMatches
        lstClaimLoaded837Data.Items.Add(strClaimData.Value)
    Next
End Function
```

I've tried a few things I've found online, such as appending a \K or \2, but I just get compile errors if I do that.

https://regex101.com/r/jH9eJ7/1

That shows what I want as "Match 1, Group 1", but I can't figure out how to get to it.  I thought appending /1 would work, but that only returned CLM* with no number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Example data would look like CLM*12345* and you just want the 12345 to be the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is wrap the `CLM\*` part in a `possitive lookbehind assertion`:

(?<=CLM\*)

What this does asserts that `(\d*\.?\d*)` is preceded by `CLM*`, but doesn't include `CLM*` in the match.

https://regex101.com/r/jH9eJ7/3

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to use the captured group.

Replace:

```
strClaimData.Value
```

with:

```
strClaimData.Groups[1].Value
```

in your for loop.